# How can I run swift AVFoundation as server-side code?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, server-side, vapor

So I have some swift code that I originally built for a native MacOS app that downloads a video from firebase, performs some AI processes on it, and then uploads several other shortened versions back to firebase.

I soon realised my customers wanted a more easily accessible interface so I've built a website and frankensteined some swift code together so that whenever I get an order, I have to manually fulfil the order.

I used vapor to try and create a server-side API however, vapor doesn't support AVFoundation and so I don't think this is a viable option as a considerable amount of my code used AVFoundation.

Is there a work around or another way I can run my swift code using the AVFoundation framework as sever-side code that executes whenever an order is made from my website?

Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance!

I used vapor to try and create a server-side API however, vapor doesn't support AVFoundation and so I don't think this is a viable option as a considerable amount of my code used AVFoundation.

Is there a work around or another way I can run my swift code using the AVFoundation framework as sever-side code that executes whenever an order is made from my website?

Any help would be amazing. Thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no generic solution to just being able to use `AVFoundation`. Perhaps if you describe what problem you're trying to solve by _using_ AVFoundation, someone may have a suggestion about how to implement that it a cross-platform way.

Comment: There is absolutely a fully supported solution (not a work-around): run it on a Mac. Vapor supports macOS 10.15 and later, which supports almost all of AVFoundation (the parts it doesn't support probably aren't relevant here). If you mean whether you can run AVFoundation on Linux, no. You'd have to port that to something that supports Linux.

Comment: @jnpdx Thanks for your response. I have a substantial amount of code written in swift that chops up long form podcast videos into short form social media clips with a little help from AI. I'm trying to run it in a way that when a user makes an order on my website, it runs the code and uploads the short-form clips it creates to their account. Does that help add any context? Appreciate it!

Comment: @RobNapier Can I run it on a Mac in a server-side like way where it would respond to website requests? How can I do this? Appreciate it

Comment: Sure. You do it just like on Linux. The tools are generally the same. If you want Mac hosting, there are services like https://www.macstadium.com for that. (I'm not particularly recommending or not recommending that particular service; just describing what exists, parallel to how you'd deploy this for Linux.) You can even run Mac instances via EC2: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/mac/   Vapor provides instructions for Mac installation. https://docs.vapor.codes/install/macos/  One installed, it generally will accept remote requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much that Vapor doesn't support AVFoundation - it's that it's only supported on macOS. So if you want to run your Vapor app on Linux you need to replace the AVFoundation code, either by using external services or other libraries (like ffmpeg etc)

The other option is you run your Vapor app on macOS. This brings problems around deployment, tooling and hosting but I know people doing this for precisely this reason

Comment: So when I run my vapor app locally that's why it works fine - because its on my MacBook? How can I run it on a Mac so it will respond to requests from my website and not just on my local machine? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Set the hostname to 0.0.0.0 to accept connections from all addresses https://docs.vapor.codes/advanced/server/#hostname